# How do I allow increment with "step='number', but allow input that fall "in between"?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input box

```
<input          step="0.25"
                min="0"
                max="1"
                ...
              />
```

Currently this allows the user to increment or decrement by 0.25 with the up/down arrow key. This is the behavior that I want.
However, it's not allowing input that isn't 0, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, or 1.0. How do I allow the user to input 0.4, for example, without getting the "Please enter a valid value. The two nearest valid values are..."

Comment: please not paste a fully functional example of the code with the undesired behavior

Comment: are you using any libraries or is this vanilla js?

Comment: is this the only `input` in your `form`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't according to the spec: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/step: "The step attribute is a number that specifies the granularity that the value *must adhere to* or the keyword any" (my emphasis). So you'd need to implement your own stepping mechanism if you want something different.